# Bash: Initializing this variable without showing it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to save in `CORE_NUMBER` the number of cores of my pc. I've tried with:

**system_info.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /proc
CORE_NUMBER= cat cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
#...
```

So that I can do something like:

**compile.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
../system_info.sh
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j$CORE_NUMBER
#...
```

When running `../system_info.sh`, the number of cores is (logically) shown in the terminal.

How can I avoid that, and just assign it to `CORE_NUMBER`?

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system_info.sh, you should use backtick to execute the command, and assign the output to variable CORE_NUMBER

```
CORE_NUMBER=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`
```

example use:

```
sharuzzaman@mylaptop ~
$ export CORE_NUMBER=`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep processor |wc -l`

sharuzzaman@mylaptop ~
$ echo $CORE_NUMBER
4
```

Comment: Those backticks... Thanks!